pointer address does not change when cast to empty base struct
The followings code shows a difference behavior when upcast a derived class to its base.
#include <cstdio>
struct base { 
  int value; 
};
template <typename T> struct wrapper: base, T {
};
struct empty {};
struct nonempty { int value; };

template <typename T>
int ofst(wrapper<T> *t) { return (char *) ((T *) t) - (char *) t; }
template <typename T>
int ofst2(wrapper<T> *t) { return (char *) static_cast<T*>(t) - (char *) t; }

int main() {
  wrapper<empty> empty;
  wrapper<nonempty> nonempty;

  printf("%d %d\n", ofst(&empty), ofst(&nonempty));    // give 0, 4
  printf("%d %d\n", ofst2(&empty), ofst2(&nonempty));  // also give 0, 4
}

Can someone gives me the reference that explains this result?

Could you explain what you think this code does so one does not need to interpret your code to grasp the subject of your question? It is going to be very hard for the next person with the same question to find this one.

Empty base optimization

@IgorTandetnik I found it, GCC's behavior. thanks

@IgorTandetnik Though in a standard-layout class type, the EBO is no longer an optimization.

The C++ Standard doesn't entirely specify which bytes of a struct or other class type are used for its base and member subobjects. Though in the special case of a "standard-layout class type" ([class.prop]/3), there are a lot more guarantees.
It happens to be that your wrapper<empty> is standard-layout but wrapper<nonempty> is not, because [class.prop]/3.6 requires a standard-layout class "has all non-static data members and bit-fields in the class and its base classes first declared in the same class". wrapper<empty> has only one non-static data member, of type int. But wrapper<empty> has two non-static data members, one first declared in base and one first declared in nonempty.
For the standard-layout wrapper<empty>, the wrapper<empty> object and empty subobject are "pointer-interconvertible" ([basic.compound]/4) and have the same address. So although it's technically undefined behavior for ofst and ofst2 to subtract pointers not pointing at elements of any array, in practice ofst(&empty) and ofst2(&empty) will normally return zero.
In earlier versions of C++, wrapper<empty> would not be standard-layout, but many compilers did choose to use the same address for the empty subobject of the wrapper<empty> as now required, and this was called the Empty Base Optimization.
Since wrapper<nonempty> is not standard-layout, it's up to the compiler how to arrange storage of its subobjects. But the most obvious thing to do here is to put the base subobject and its int before the nonempty subobject and its int, based on the order the base classes are listed in the wrapper class template definition. So it makes sense to see that ofst(&nonempty) and ofst2(&nonempty) return a positive value. Again, the caveat about undefined behavior applies.
